# When should I say "AM" / "PM" and when should I say "o'clock"?

Tags: time

When I am asked "**what time is it**", when should I say "**It is 1 o'clock**" and when I should say "**It is 1 AM /PM**"? and in addition, could it be that both of them can be said continuously (It is 1 AM / PM o'clock)?

Comment: "It's 6 AM" or "6 PM" is short for "It's 6 [o'clock] in the morning/afternoon” Adding the abbreviations makes the response unnecessarily  *longer*. Never say: "It's 6 o'clock PM“

Answer (score 1):

Speaking both PM/AM and o'clock together is *odd!*

> It's 4 PM o'clock - ***no, no....***

Now, it depends on the context. If someone is asking you *now,* obviously both of you know the *part* of the day or night. It makes no sense to add PM if the person is asking you in the afternoon. Yes, this is ***okay*** if you are *teaching* someone when to say PM/AM.

So, if the context is clear, you both *know* the part of the day, calling it 'o'clock' is *common.*

> Hey, what's the time? ~ It's 3 o'clock (obviously, you both know that it is *day* and not night.

On the other hand, if you are telling a reference as in the past or in future, calling it with PM/AM is common just to clarify which part of the day/night you are talking about.

> My train departs at 4 AM tomorrow

Because here, if you say 'o'clock,' the next question will be when? Early morning or in the evening?

However, what all I said is just *in a general context.* Special cases always do exist!

Answer (score 0):

### How to state the time

For stating times like this, you many options (they do not mix together naturally):

1. `It is 1 o'clock (optional set phrase here)`. Typically the set phrases are `in the morning`, `in the afternoon`, `noon` (only for 12:00pm), `at night`, `midnight` (only for 12am). If you have a set phrase, you can leave out the `o'clock` but do not need to. There are also set phrases like `on the dot` or `sharp` to emphasize that the event will happen at the exact time stated.

For example

> It's 4 in the afternoon (16:00)
>
> It's 3 o'clock (3:00 or 15:00 depending on context)
>
> It's 7 o'clock in the morning (7:00)
>
> We will meet at 12 noon, correct? (The meeting is at 12:00)
>
> I woke up yesterday morning at 2 o'clock. (The speaker woke up yesterday at 2:00)

2. `It is 1(am/pm)`

It common to leave out the o'clock or am/pm when there is no ambiguity when speaking. For example,

> When's the next match?
>
> It's at 2

Based on the current time the two speakers can infer the am/pm.

However, saying `It's 2` by itself is uncommon: the o'clock is needed to specify that the current *time* is 2.

### Usage

#### For business documents

Am/pm or 24-hour time are typically used.

#### Telling time

For exact hours (1:00, 2:00, 3:00, ...) it is typical to say `1 o'clock` when stating the time because as mentioned above, `It's 1` by itself is ambiguous.

For non-exact hours (1:01, 3:30, 4:12) it is typical to say `one thirty`, `three thirty`, or `four twelve`. These sequences are rare outside of telling time, so they work on their own.